# WSO2 API Manager - Add client roles to password grant JWT

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

how do I add user roles to JWT generated through OAuth2 Password Grant as described [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/password-grant/):

I tried [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/passing-end-user-attributes-to-the-backend/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-using-) approach but it adds custom claims only to JWT passed to backend but there is nothing in JWT used to authenticate clients.

What I'm trying to do is to add a login page to Angular application and call `https://[APIM]/token` to get token when successful authentication occurs. Roles are important to render correct menus based on user roles.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the token with openid scope to retrieve the additional user information as claims of the JWT token. You can refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/openid-connect/obtaining-user-profile-information-with-openid-connect/ for more details.

For instance, if you want to get the user roles in the generated JWT, you can add the `http://wso2.org/claims/role` claim as a requested claim under `Claim Configuration` to the service provider you are using from the carbon console. Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-claims-for-a-service-provider/#claim-mapping for more details.

Then when you are invoking the token endpoint, you need to add the openid scope.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>&scope=openid" -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE64 ENCODED CONSUMER_KEY:CONSUMER_SECRET>, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://<GATEWAY_HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/token
```

The generated JWT token payload will be something like this,

```
{
  "sub": "admin",
  "aut": "APPLICATION_USER",
  "aud": "5af6EfSzqxS_dfmUnQ28sHdpZzYa",
  "nbf": 1610395871,
  "azp": "5af6EfSzqxS_dfmUnQ28sHdpZzYa",
  "scope": "openid",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token",
  "groups": [
    "Internal/subscriber",
    "Internal/creator",
    "Application/admin_DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION",
    "Application/apim_devportal",
    "Internal/publisher",
    "Internal/everyone",
    "Internal/devops",
    "Application/apim_admin_portal",
    "admin",
    "Internal/analytics",
    "Application/apim_publisher"
  ],
  "exp": 1610399471,
  "iat": 1610395871,
  "jti": "75ddfca2-5088-435d-825a-3320efc10036"
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes, you're right, I made another question and got the answer for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792575/wso2-apim-add-user-roles-in-jwt-payload. But your answer is right, I'll mark it as correct to help others. Thank you!